# Problem in creating .urdf files

Tags: gazebo, urdf, moveit, xacro, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I want to create .urdf file from the file lwa.urdf.xacro.
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS distribution is indigo.

In the folder: `opt/ros/indigo/stacks/schunk_description/urdf/lwa`

There are 3 files:

- lwa.gazebo.xacro
- lwa.transmission.xacro
- lwa.urdf.xacro

In terminal, I direct to this directory and command:

```
ros@ros:~$ rosrun xacro xacro.py lwa.urdf.xacro > lwa.urdf

ros@ros:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/urdf/lwa$ rosrun xacro xacro.py lwa.urdf.xacro > lwa.urdf
bash: lwa.urdf: Permission denied
```

I know that my question might be somehow silly. I am sorry but it probably refers to my lack of proper knowledge, esp. with Linux. I just guess it must have something to do with permissions.
I would appreciate if someone help me or share his/her experience in creating .urdf files with me.

Thanks a lot,

Damon

P.S.
Why do I need .urdf file? Gazebo works with .xacro files smoothly and I already can load the robot in gazebo or send the commands to it.
The point is that I want to use Moveit! Moveit has an "assistant" which helps you make Moveit recognize your robot. When I load xacro file of PR2 robot in Moveit, the assistant works fine and seemingly creates a .urdf file for itself. But this doesn't work when I load xacro file of schunk. And the reason is that Moveit tries to build .urdf file and fails.
This makes me feel if I want moveit work, I should first be able to create .urdf files.

---

Edit:

First of all, thanks for your time and attention. :)
xacro has been introduced to replace urdf. Basically we should be able to create urdf from xacro. My schunk package (schunk_description) is in:
opt/ros/indigo/stacks/schunk_modular_robotics

I thought if the problem is permissions, what if I try to make a copy of the package somewhere else and try again. So I copied the package to /Documents. And:

```
ros@ros:~$ cd Documents

ros@ros:~/Documents$ cd schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/urdf/lwa

ros@ros:~/Documents/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/urdf/lwa$ rosrun xacro xacro.py lwa.urdf.xacro > lwa.urdf
```

This created an empty .urdf file. Here is the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from lwa.urdf.xacro                 | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
</robot>
```

Moveit used to use .urdf file. But recently, they say the user can also browse to .xacro file as well.
I think this is exactly what Moveit tries to do automatically, and probably the urdf file is also created. But since it is empty, Moveit fails.
Here is when I try to browse the lwa.urdf.xacro file in Moveit:

An error message shown by setup assistant in a small window: "URDF/COLLADA file is not a valid robot model."

And when I look at the terminal, I see this:

```
[rospack] Error: no package given
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ INFO] [1434379501.633977236]: Running 'rosrun xacro xacro.py /opt/ros/indigo/share/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/urdf/lwa/lwa.urdf.xacro'...
[ERROR] [1434379501.934726406]: No name given for the robot.
```

As you see, it seemingly tries to do what I try and fail: creating .urdf from .xacro.
Then I do another experiment: I was able to create the urdf, when I copied the whole package in my "Documents", where probably permissions are not troublesome. In there the .urdf is created, but empty. This time, I browse that empty .urdf file to see the reaction of Moveit:

```
[rospack] Error: no package given
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1434379684.002977198]: No name given for the robot.
```

The same thing! Which possibly means, the problem is not Moveit. The problem is created .urdf file, and as you mentioned, maybe there is something wrong with schunk .xacro file. :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211342/problem-in-creating-.urdf-files/) by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-15**:
It is a permission error: you (as a regular user) cannot write in that directory. But (and this will sound a bit pedantic) a better approach would be to figure out what is wrong with the schunk xacros. The Setup Assistant should be able to load it just fine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-15**:
Could you update (edit) your question with what  "it doesn't work" actually means? If you get any error output on the console, please copy/paste that into your question as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-15**:
Again a bit pedantic, but: please don't use answers to post updates. Either use a comment, or edit your original post. I've moved the content of your answer as an edit to your original question.

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-06-15**:
Ow thanks. Sorry, today is my first day in this forum! Need to learn how to post things and format them properly.

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-06-15**:
HaHa! I was wondering how my writing turned to be so nicely formatted! Automatically?! So you had done it! :D

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-15**:
No problem. Formatting isn't too hard: just use the buttons on the formatting bar above the text area. For console copy/paste, use the *preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can read on the [schunk_description](http://wiki.ros.org/schunk_description) wiki page:

> This package contains the description (mechanical, kinematic, visual, etc.) of different schunk components. The files in this package are parsed and used by a variety of other components. **Most users will not interact directly with this package**.

One of the consequences of this setup seems to be that the package only contains xacro *macros* and no top-level entities that would invoke those macros to create a valid urdf file (you probably got a "*URDF/COLLADA file is not a valid robot model*" together with a "*No name given for the robot*" error from the Setup Assistant).

> This makes me feel if I want moveit work, I should first be able to create .urdf files.

That is partly true: the Setup Assistant needs a valid urdf, and you'll only get that if you create a top-level xacro that invokes the `schunk_lwa` macro. Something like the following should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="my_robot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- we 'import' the macro definition from that file -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find schunk_description)/urdf/lwa/lwa.urdf.xacro"/>

  <!-- this could be anything, but you need a 'parent' link -->
  <link name="world" />

  <!-- here we 'call' the macro and supply it with the required arguments -->
  <xacro:schunk_lwa parent="world" name="my_lwa">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
  </xacro:schunk_lwa>
</robot>
```

Call this `my_lwa.xacro` (or something), place it in a package that is on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` (basically, it should be in your ROS workspace) and load it in the Setup Assistant. It should then be able to load your LWA.

Note: I use the term *top-level xacro file* to refer to any xacro that doesn't (only) declare xacro macros itself. All files that can be converted to a valid urdf using `rosrun xacro xacro ..` I consider top-level.

So just to conclude: there is nothing wrong with the xacros in `schunk_description`, they are just not top-level xacros, meaning you cannot use them directly, but only as building blocks in other xacros.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-06-15**:
Thanks again for your time and helps gvdhoom. I was writing some additional notes related to my question that I saw your answer right after I posted my writing. Your guesses are so true! Please take a look at my update: Exactly as you guessed: invalid urdf error. And "no name given for the robot"...

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-06-15**:
Second update:
Thanks for the answer gvdhoom. I tried your approach and what I'm seeing for now is that the robot is loaded in Moveit! :)

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-24**:
I also met the same question when I changed some thing in the jaka.urdf.xacro and `shantengfei@shantengfei-pc:~/catkin_ws/src/jaka/urdf$ rosrun xacro xacro.py jaka.urdf.xacro > jakA.urdf`  then it ouput `bash: jakA.urdf: Permission denied`  I don't understand the **Note**. Could you give more detail

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-24**:
@tengfei: are you not running into the same problem as in #q273819? Is your entire workspace owned by `root` or just some pkgs?

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-24**:
oh, yes. Sorry to ask again.